# More structure with subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a lot of controllers, models and views and I want them to be structured in subfolders. I can do that with something like this:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

But what if I want to have more nested subfolders, like:

```
/app/models/platform/user/*
```

What way would my autoload paths look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can already use subfolders, but rails will consider that your classes are namespaced. Ie. if you have `app/models/platform/user.rb`, this file is expected to define `Platform::User`.

I don't know if you can (and if it is a good idea, since it goes against the framework conventions) use subfolders without namespacing.

Comment: It would be convenient, because it's only to keep things organized in my folder structure, I don't have any deeper rails meaning with it.